# Jquery length on append and remove clicks

Tags: jquery

I need to get the length of the number of divs using jQuery.

I can get it but declaring the variable in both click events but this seems wrong and also I then need to use it to show hide a button depending on the number.  I feel like I shouldn't have to double up the code.

Fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqsf45a/51/

```
$("button#add").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(document.body).append($("<div>"));

 var n = $("div").length;
  $("span").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
  if (n < 2) {
    $('#showhide').hide()
  } else {
    $('#showhide').show()
  }


});

$("body").on("click", "div", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("div").remove();

  var n = $("div").length;
  $("span").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
  if (n < 2) {
    $('#showhide').hide()
  } else {
    $('#showhide').show()
  }

});
```

Comment: If you don't want to duplicate the code then move it to a function and call that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep this DRY you can extract the common logic out to its own function and call it where needed:

```js
$("button#add").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body').append('<div>');
  countDivs();
});

$("body").on("click", "div", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").remove();
  countDivs();
});

function countDivs() {
  var n = $("div").length;
  $("span").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
  $('#showhide').toggle(n >= 2);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<button id="add">
  add
</button>

<p>
  <button id="showhide">
    show / hide
  </button>
</p>
```

Note that I removed `preventDefault()` on the `div` click handler as it's not required. It's arguably not needed on the `button` click handler either - assuming the production version of the button isn't contained in a form, as in your example.